# How to parse JSON and have 2 final arrays of data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

I am parsing an itunes rss feed with JSON but I have run into a problem. The following code is running properly for one the movieName output but I still don't get the movieSummary output.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    feed = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];
    arrayOfEntry = [feed objectForKey:@"entry"];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionTitle in arrayOfEntry) {

        NSDictionary *title = [dictionTitle objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *labelTitle = [title objectForKey:@"label"];

        [arrayLable addObject:labelTitle];

        NSDictionary *summary = [dictionTitle objectForKey:@"summary"];
        NSString *labelSummary = [summary objectForKey:@"label"];

        [arraySummary addObject:labelSummary];
    }

    movieName.text = [arrayLable objectAtIndex:0];
    movieSummary.text = [arraySummary objectAtIndex:0]; //This is not displaying 
}
```

Here is the link that I am parsing: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=300/json

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you initialised `arraySummary`?

Comment: as soon as i do that the app crashes. This is what im doing ti initialise the 2 arrays arrayLable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [arrayLable removeAllObjects]; arraySummary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [arraySummary removeAllObjects]; While already having the arrayLable initialized the app works as soon as I initialise the arraySummary it crashes.

Comment: And how are you defining/declaring arraySummary?

Comment: Well what im doing is in the Interface I add the following: `interface FirstViewController ()  {
    
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableArray *arrayLable;
    NSMutableArray *arraySummary;
}

end`.  I am guessing that is what you are asking for. Btw im really appreciating the help.

Comment: All your array handling seems correct. Does labelSummary have a value? What happens if you put `NSLog(@"Summary: %@", labelSummary);` below the creation of labelSummary?

Comment: Ok, if I add the 2 NSLogs (1 for Title and 1 for Summary) then the app crashes. The logoutput gives me the correct results until the last output witch will give me a title but no summary. labelSummary just equals null and then it gives me this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

Comment: And if you log your `summary` dictionary does it look correct? The array is complaining that you're trying to insert a nil object into it - it looks like `[summary objectForKey:@"label]` is returning nil.

Comment: N0 it returns the correct info as well. Its when I add this line of code that the app crashes `[arraySummary addObject:labelSummary];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this situation a lot. I use something like this. Replace your code

```
NSString *labelTitle = [title objectForKey:@"label"];
[arrayLable addObject:labelTitle];
```

with

```
NSString * labelTitle = [ [ title objectForKey:@"label" ] ifNullThenNil ] ;
[ arrayLabel addObject:labelTitle ? labelTitle : @"" ] ; // you could also use @"<unknown>" or similar instead of @""
```

where `-ifNullThenNil` is provided via category:

```
@implementation NSObject (IfNullThenNil)
-(id)ifNullThenNil { return self ; }
@end

@implementation NSNull (IfNullThenNil)
-(id)ifNullThenNil { return nil ; }
@end
```

Comment: Yes this looks much cleaner and simpler to be quite honest

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I was adding the strings to the Array that it sometimes contained NULL's thus the following code helped me out

```
    if ([[arrayName objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    labelName.text = @"This is NULL";
} else {
    [arrayName addObject:labelName];
}

    if ([[arraySummary objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    labelSummary.text = @"This is NULL";
} else {
    [arraySummary addObject:labelSummary];
}
```